# Installing Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

I am installing Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers. My old copy went rogue and decided to act up.

So clean install time! Yay! I downloaded the new version, copied it to the `opt` folder, extracted it, and ran it.

For some reason, I can't install any plugins due to some crap error*, and it doesn't have a list of default plugins. I deleted my workspace and the original Eclipse install.

Is there another file that is helping Eclipse keep data from previous installs? I am seeing update sites I added when I was constantly trying to get past this issue.

Also, why can't I install new plugins?

I need a clean install so I can't use the Ubuntu installer.

Any tips are appreciated.

*`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.10.2.20100623-1649 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.10.2.20100623-1649)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 0.10.2.20100623-1649 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor 0.10.2.20100623-1649) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.10.2.20100623-1649 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.10.2.20100623-1649)
    To: org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor [0.10.2.20100623-1649]`

Comment: Perhaps list the error instead of simplying referring to it as "some crap error"? That'd be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when doing a fresh install of Java EE eclipse (helios, galileo, win32 and win64).

**The solution for me was to explicitly open the Java perspective, and doing the install after this. This time the installation worked fine.**

I suspect the reason is that after a fresh install not all bundles are loaded (although they are present on disk; a feature of eclipse) so that the dependencies cannot be resolved. Opening the Java perspective or creating a dummy Java project will force to load these bundles. Once a bundle is loaded, its existence is persisted, so this only has to happen once.

This issue was mentioned a number of time on the official websites, but always closed or neglected, probably because the reproducer did not do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Download Eclipse 2018-19 (4.9.0) version as an updated eclipse version and install it! Maven dependency will presented inbuild thing in that model, Right click on project -> properties -> on left pane, Maven will display ! Change your setting there to overcome this error and you can add external JAR'S there